# Ask for a facility visit to another Japanese company

Tags: word-choice, keigo, formality, sonkeigo

I'm in the process of asking another company if they would be so kind to let us visit their facility. Some kind of tour of the company.

They already accepted us going there, but we would like to ask to see the facility.

What is the correct expression for it? My best guess is:

> ところで、御社のファシリティの訪問させていただけませんでしょうか。

I feel like the world ツアーstrictly refers to a touristic setting.

Comment: I would use 施設 instead of ファシリティ.

Answer (score 3):

So, you are already allowed to visit the place and enter their reception/guest/meeting room? And you are trying to ask for a detailed tour of the lab/factory/etc where employees are actually working? In this case, ファシリティの訪問 doesn't convey your intention; it usually just means going there and talking to someone at the front desk, which is already accepted. And ファシリティ is not really a common loanword.

Instead, you can use 施設内の見学/案内 (見学 is what *you* do, 案内 is what *they* do). Note the 内 which explicitly expresses "inside (the facility)". Depending on the type of the facility, instead of 施設, it may better to use a more concrete word such as 工場, 生産ライン, データセンター, 研究施設 or 倉庫.

> - 御社の施設内を見学させていただくことは可能でしょうか。
> - 御社の実際の施設内を案内していただくことは可能でしょうか。